# Android studio : Package androidx.activity.result not found

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, onactivityresult

I use the new way of registering callback of launched Activity result

```
 activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        }
    }
```

But Android studio complains about result package as it is not found

build.gradle

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
} implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0
```

Comment: Did you add the dependency for the new results API? Example: dependencies { implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-beta02" }

Comment: Have you added ``androidx.activity`` as a dependency? (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) You need the non-stable version to use the ``Result`` API

Comment: v1.2.0-beta02 worked , thx